# Filter list for objects missing a property

Tags: powershell

I have a generic list of custom objects that look like this:

```
id             : 1
displayName    : server1.domain.tdl
autoProperties : { @{name = auto.bios_version; value = 6.00 }, @{name = auto.specialDevice; value = True} }

id             : 2
displayName    : server2.domain.tdl
autoProperties : { @{name = auto.bios_version; value = 6.00 } }
```

Some of them have the "auto.SpecialDevice" property and some do not. I am trying to filter out those that do NOT have "auto.SpecialDevice".

As a sample, this code gets to what I have:

```
$string = '    [
        {
            "id":  1,
            "displayName": "server1.domain.tdl",
            "autoProperties":  [
                {
                    "name":  "auto.bios_version",
                    "value":  "6.00"
                },
                {
                    "name":  "auto.specialDevice",
                    "value":  "True"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":  2,
            "displayName": "server2.domain.tdl",
            "autoProperties":  [
                {
                    "name":  "auto.bios_version",
                    "value":  "6.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
'
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::New()
$list.Add(($string | ConvertFrom-Json))
```

So, the objects are in a variable called, $list, then I have tried the following, which returns both devices:

```
$list | Where-Object { -Not $_.autoProperties['auto.specialDevice'] }
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your `$list.Add(($string | ConvertFrom-Json))` nests an array as the first element of `$list`. So currently your array of objects is in `$list[0]`.  If you instead use `$list = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $string` then Mike Shepard's answer below will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(adding list population code suggested by @ansgar wiechers and @john rees)

You can populate the list from that json like this:

`$list = $string | ConvertFrom-Json`

Once you have the list populated with these objects, the following will work:

`$list | where {$_.Autoproperties.name -notcontains 'auto.specialDevice'}`

That is because `$_.AutoProperties.name` is a list of all of the names in the autoproperties collection.

Comment: If for some reason you feel that you just *need* that specific list type you could do `[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]$list = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $string` to strongly type the `$list` variable.